# Eclipse ADT NDK plugin 23.0.3 Hangs indexer

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, adt, indexer

I recently updated the ADT eclipse plugin from 22.x to 23.0.3. Being aware that there is a bug that blocks a clean update, i downloaded ADT from scratch, so to make the suggested workaround.

Only with the ADT bundle, there is no support for native development (NDK), which I need for my project, and so I downloaded the NDK suport using the classic install new software...

No problems with the installation at all, I restarted eclipse to find that the indexer, working fine until then, gets blocked at some point (the % reached is irrelevant, since it changes everytime I try), and I have to restart eclipse, since it does not respond while using 93% of CPU.

Do you know if there is anything wrong with the newest adt package? (the actual version is 23.0.3.1327240). If so, is there any workaround to enable native support without getting this problem?